# angular-ngrx-data create custom effect

Tags: ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I am currently using ngrx in my app to manage state. I was looking at switching to ngrx-data for the simple CRUD operations and ran across my first question. This is my current regular ngrx effect and I want to know how to reproduce it with ngrx-data (create new action based on http response):

```
@Effect()
insertUser$: Observable<Action> = this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(UsersActionTypes.UserInsert),
    map((action: UserInsert) => action.payload),
    mergeMap(payload =>
        this.UserService.insert(<IUserPersistRequest>{
            user: payload.User,
            refreshToken: payload.loggedInUser.RefreshToken
        }).pipe(
            map((response: IUserPersistResponse) => {
                return !response.accessToken
                        ? new UserPersistSuccessLoginFailure()
                        : new UserInsertSuccess({
                            response: response,
                            User: payload.User
                        });
            }),
            catchError((error: string) => {
                return of(new UserInsertFailure('UserInsert Failed'));
            })
        )
    )
);
```

Any advice?

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: have there been any updates / success with that, @samneric?

Comment: I haven't looked at it lately, I will revisit on the weekend.

Comment: @samneric can answer without knowing `UserService` API. for example what's `IUserPersistResponse`?

Comment: for the purposes of this question, you can assume IUserPersistResponse contains just one string: 'accessToken'. If that field is present in the response, UserInsertSuccess action is returned else UserPersistSuccessLoginFailure is returned.